# Permissions for Large Variables to Be Sent Via Stored Procedures (SQL Server)

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, types, varbinary

I can't figure out a way to allow more than 4000 bytes to be received at once via a call to a stored procedure. I am storing images in the table that are around 15 - 20 kilobytes each, but upon getting them and displaying them to the page, they are always exactly 3.91 KB in size (or 4000 bytes).

Do stored procedures have a limit on how much data can be sent at once? I double-checked my data, and I am indeed only receiving the first 4000 characters from the `varbinary(MAX)` field.

Is there a permission setting to allow more than 4k bytes at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Using Large-Value Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx)

> The max specifier expands the storage
>   capabilities of the varchar, nvarchar,
>   and varbinary data types.
>   varchar(max), nvarchar(max), and
>   varbinary(max) are collectively called
>   large-value data types. You can use
>   the large-value data types to store up
>   to 2^31-1 bytes of data.
>
> The large-value data types are similar
>   in behavior to their smaller
>   counterparts, varchar, nvarchar and
>   varbinary.

If you can't pass more than 4000 bytes, I'd check in your client application to see if it is limiting or truncating your data.  SQL Server can take more than 4000 bytes at one time.

**EDIT** just found this:

[EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

> Using EXECUTE with a Character String
>
> In earlier versions of SQL Server,
>   character strings are limited to 8,000
>   bytes. This requires concatenating
>   large strings for dynamic execution.
>   In SQL Server, the varchar(max) and
>   nvarchar(max) data types can be
>   specified that allow for character
>   strings to be up to 2 gigabytes of
>   data.

Comment: The image that's getting displayed is 4000 bytes, but I'm thinking that the SP is actually getting 8,000 bytes. I think I'm losing half the bytes when pulling it from the DB in hex form and then turning it into an image, so that makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different code to access BLOBs in SQL Server. Example [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_read_write_blob.html).

Comment: My shift is ending right now so I'll check that tomorrow morning and see if it helps at all. I should also mention that I'm using PHP to access the database.

Comment: Then this article will probably be useless to you as the sample is for ado.net. Look into accessing BLOBs for your particular method of accessing data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a data type called "image" in SQL Server 2005. You should use that data type to store large binary object especially images.

Comment: **ntext, text, and image  data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them.** Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max)  instead.  Fixed and variable-length data types for storing large non-Unicode and Unicode character and binary data. Unicode data uses the UNICODE UCS-2 character set. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx